# Error accessing Catalog > Manage Categories

Tags: category, error, catalog

When I am trying to access `Catalog > Manage categories`, I am having the below error:

> Source model "defaultcatview/category_attribute_source_view" not found
> for attribute "default_cat_list_view"

Comment: Please double check what the attribute is before deleting it as you dont know if this will cause further issues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed a third pary module, and you don't uninstalled this in the right form.

I think that an attribute in database table `eav_attribute` are making the conflict.

Execute this SQL code in your database:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'default_cat_list_view';
```